# How shoud i schedule my Views templates in django?

Tags: python, django

I need to  run my view for specific time in my schedule days.  how I can make it ?

Answer (score 1):

You could for example use a [Cron Job](https://gutsytechster.wordpress.com/2019/06/24/how-to-setup-a-cron-job-in-django/) oder [Celery Beat](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/userguide/periodic-tasks.html) for this.

Answer (score 0):

APScheduler is quick and easy https://apscheduler.readthedocs.io/en/3.x/